# Manipulate html element by click on a children element with a directive

Tags: angular

I want to develop a directive that should has follow functionality:

1. Captures the last element of the element on which the directive is added
2. Adds to this last element (in this case a button) the click-EventListener
3. On click, a boolean should get toggled
4. Based on this boolean, a new css class should get added to the base element.

In my current try I use @ContentChild to get the button. Than I added the interface AfterViewInit to the directive. In ngAfterViewInit() I register the click-event on the button with the function toggleMenu. In this function I just toggle the boolean to true or false. To add the css class to the base element I use @HostBinding() with the boolean, that is toggled.

The problem that I have is, that this doesn't work. The click-event fires and the boolean value changes to, but no css class is added. I don't know why.

This is the code:

```
    export class ToggleSidemenuDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChild('toggleBtn') element: ElementRef;
  private btn: HTMLBodyElement;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.btn = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.toggleMenu);
  }

  @HostBinding("class.sidemenu-toggled") toggled = true;

  private toggleMenu(){
    this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    console.log(this.toggled)
  }
}
```

Has anyone an idea, why this doesn't work?

Comment: Do you want to use a directive because you want this code to be reusable? If not I suggest adding this logic to the component.

Comment: In general try not to use `addEventListener` with angular. Rather use `(click)` in a template to do this. To me it's also not clear why you would need a directive here, move this logic to the component. And re-use the component where you need this functionality. Store the toggle status in service so it can be re-used in multiple components.

Comment: I've just learned what directives are and what kind of directives exist. Now I want to use them to implement functionality like this. I decided to use a directive in this case, because I only must use this directive to add this functionality that is usually added via a component and EventBinding. To do it in a directive is much less work and you have all the code only in one place. 

When are you suggest to use structural directives?

Answer (score 0):

ContentChild only gets the "first", you should use ContentChildren and get the last

```
//it's a QueryList
@ContentChildren('toggleBtn') elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  private btn: HTMLBodyElement;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //You get the last element of the queryList using last
    this.btn = this.elements.last.nativeElement;
    this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.toggleMenu);
  }
```